# Web push notification - Do I need to own a server?

Tags: javascript, push-notification, google-chrome-devtools, web-push

I have achieved a simple push notification using source code from here: [https://itnext.io/an-introduction-to-web-push-notifications-a701783917ce][1]

But I want to do more advance by sending push notification remotely to another computer using Chrome like Facebook and some others do.

Now I am able to register subscription and get the endpoint link like this:
{

```
  "endpoint": "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send/cThXDSA40Mo:APA91bE7lTJvxlF52GsX6huXPogc7C-nAcCrX6r9WrMSAwWToz7UDexDnLnAJJdoG-FSbQfquR8bjpd5Oc_CZQYTHU12gF_7_YmdK06CV77uXhSB6M-6LkmdjMazU5MQisXgjyUEICEd",
  "keys": {
    "p256dh":
"BGaCEBZSsJoqLU_l1hFWpFRwYMH8dHPkfPrPfyO2Sev_ilBYfFwJ7w4W-ppwKmxdhNTcACbi3sf7f0qerSNmQBI",
    "auth":"FPssMOQPmLmXWmdSTdbKVw=="
  }
}
```

But I don´t know how to go forward with this. Still wonder if I need to own a server or not ?

Answer (score 1):

It helps if you have a server, so you can see every step of the process and understand what's happening, but if you strictly want to test your app you could use [this companion site](https://web-push-codelab.glitch.me/) to send a notification.